# A very simple proof of a divergent sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I've already proved that: if $\,0 <x< 1$, then $(x^n)\rightarrow0$. Now I'm wondering about the opposite, when $x>1$ which clearly diverges. I'd like to know if the following approach is correct or maybe I need more sophisticated  arguments.

Scratchwork: Let $x>1$ and suppose by contradiction that $(x^n) \rightarrow L$. Since $0<1/x<1$, we can conclude $(1/x)^n\rightarrow 0$ (using the last proposition). We thus see from the limit laws that $x^n(1/x)^n\rightarrow L\cdot0=0$, but $x^n(1/x)^n=1$ and since $(\,1\,)\rightarrow 1$,  we thus have $1=0$ by the uniqueness of the limit, which is a contradiction. Thus the sequences diverges.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can $(1)\to 1$ be a contradiction?

Comment: The proof could use a bit of polishing but overall it looks to be correct. (Assuming what André pointed out was a typo).

Comment: Because the sequence $(x^n(1/x)^n)$ is the same as $(1)$. In the first case, we can get $(x^n(1/x)^n))\rightarrow 0$, but in the second $(1)\rightarrow 1$ and since both are the same sequence cannot have different limits. Well, that was the way as I thought.

Comment: @JoseAntonio: The contradiction is that this would imply $(1)\to 0$, not $(1)\to 1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: he concludes that the limit is both $0$ and $1$. I believe that is the contradiction.

Comment: @robjohn: Yes, that was exactly the way I had thought

Comment: Yes, one can guess what OP was thinking. But the contradiction should be made explicit.

Comment: I edited. Hopefully, I've fixed the problem. Thanks to everyone for  its suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove it is this : Suppose $x^n \to L$, then consider the function
$$
f(y) = xy
$$
This is continuous, so if $a_n = x^n \to L$, then $f(a_n) = x^{n+1} \to xL$. But $\{f(a_n)\}$ is the same sequence as $\{a_n\}$, so it must follow that
$$
xL = L
$$
Since $x \neq 0$, $L = 0$, but $a_n > 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $L \geq 1$ - this is a contradiction.

Comment: I used a similar argument for the other other one, when $x<1$. Thanks as always very helpful.